# How to execute 2 SQL statements inside a CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I have the following SQL query statement:

```
INSERT INTO @mt_API
    SELECT 
        [dbo].fn_AddTimeZoneOffset(APHIST.ActionDate,'CET') AS ASDATE
        , [dbo].fn_AddTimeZoneOffset(APHIST.ReturnDate,'CET') AS ATDATE
        ,API_HIST.[ActionPlanItemID]
        ,API_HIST.[ActionPlanID]
        ,PIT.[ProductItemID]
        ,PIT.ProductItemCode
        ,PIT.QRCode
        ,PIT.Name
        ,ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 mRSP.TotalRemainingAtStore FROM @mt_RemainingStockProduct AS mRSP 
            WHERE mRSP.InventoryDate <= APHIST.ReturnDate
            ORDER BY mRSP.InventoryDate DESC), 0) AS StoreTotalStock
        ,P.[Weight] AS ItemWeight
        ,M.UnitMeasureCode as Unit
        ,PIT.Quantity AS ItemQuantity
        ,P.ItemUnitWeight
        ,P.Quantity as ProductQuantity
        ,E1.FullName AS Emp1
        ,E2.FullName AS Emp2
        ,E3.FullName AS Emp3
        ,E4.FullName AS Emp4
        ,SECT.Name AS Sector
        ,CASE WHEN n=0 then 0 else [ItemStatus] end as [ItemStatus]
        ,APHIST.IsActionOver as ActionOver
    FROM 
        [Sales].[ActionPlanItem_History] AS API_HIST
    INNER JOIN 
        [Sales].[ActionPlan_History] AS APHIST On APHIST.ActionPlanID =  API_HIST.ActionPlanID
    INNER JOIN
        [Production].[ProductItem] AS PIT ON API_HIST.ProductItemID =PIT.ProductItemID
    INNER JOIN
        Production.Product as P ON PIT.ProductID = P.ProductID AND PIT.ProductID = P.ProductID AND 
            PIT.ProductID = P.ProductID
    INNER JOIN
        Production.UnitMeasure as M ON M.UnitMeasureID = P.WeightUnitMeasureID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Sales.Employee AS E1 ON APHIST.EmployeeID1 = E1.EmployeeID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Sales.Employee AS E2 ON APHIST.EmployeeID2 = E2.EmployeeID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Sales.Employee AS E3 ON APHIST.EmployeeID3 = E3.EmployeeID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Sales.Employee AS E4 ON APHIST.EmployeeID4 = E4.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN
        Sales.Sector AS SECT ON APHIST.SectorID = SECT.SectorID
    INNER JOIN
        Production.ProductSubcategory as PS on P.ProductSubcategoryID=PS.ProductSubcategoryID
    INNER JOIN 
        Production.ProductCategory as PC on PS.ProductCategoryID= PC.ProductCategoryID

    CROSS APPLY (Values(0),(1)) d(n)
    WHERE  P.StoreID=@StoreID
    --WHERE PC.ProductCategoryID=@RootCategory AND P.StoreID=@StoreID

    --ORDER BY ProductItemCode, ATDATE 
    ORDER BY ASDATE , ProductItemCode

    SELECT 
         API1.ASDATE AS StartDate
        ,API1.ATDATE AS ReturnDate
        ,API1.ActionPlanItemID
        ,API1.ActionPlanID
        ,API1.ProductItemID
        ,API1.ProductItemCode
        ,API1.QRCode
        ,API1.Name
        ,API1.StoreTotalStock
        ,API1.ItemWeight
        ,API1.ItemQuantity
        ,API1.ItemUnitWeight
        ,API1.Unit
        ,API1.ProductQuantity
        ,API1.Emp1
        ,API1.Emp2
        ,API1.Emp3
        ,API1.Emp4
        ,API1.Sector
        ,API1.ItemStatus
        ,API1.ActionOver
        ,(API1.StoreTotalStock +
            (SELECT SUM(
                CASE API2.ItemStatus 
                    WHEN 0 THEN -1
                    WHEN 1 THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END * API2.ItemUnitWeight) 
            FROM @mt_API AS API2
                WHERE API2.ID <= API1.ID
            ) 

                -
            (

                **select 
                    case ISNULL(SUM([ProductItemWeight]), 0)
                        when 0 then 0
                        else SUM([ProductItemWeight])
                    end  
                from [ExplosiveTracking].[Production].[TransfertHistory]
                where stuff(convert(varchar(20),TransfertDateTime,120),17,6,'') < stuff(convert(varchar(20),API1.ASDATE,120),17,6,'')**



            ) 
        ) AS ItemWeightBal

    FROM @mt_API  AS API1
```

Inside the `CASE` statement I am returning the `SUM([ProductItemWeight])` if it is not NULL, but then at same time, I need to execute the following inside the same `CASE` :

```
    delete from #tempTransfert
    where stuff(convert(varchar(20),#tempTransfert.TransferDate,120),17,6,'') < stuff(convert(varchar(20),API1.ASDATE,120),17,6,'')
```

ADDED MORE TEST :

If I run what I wan to accomplish in a standalone new query as below then the DELETE and SELECT works find inside the CASE

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTransfert 
(
 [ID] uniqueidentifier,
 [ProductId] int,
  [SourceId] int,
 TransferDate DateTime,
 TotalMovedProduct DECIMAL(16,4)
 )

 Insert into #tempTransfert
    select
        [ID],[ProductId], [SourceId], stuff(convert(varchar(20),TransfertDateTime,120),17,6,'') as TransferDate, SUM([ProductItemWeight]) as TotalMovedProduct
    from [ExplosiveTracking].[Production].[TransfertHistory]
    group by [ProductId],ID, [SourceId], stuff(convert(varchar(20),TransfertDateTime,120),17,6,'')


    select * from #tempTransfert


    MERGE #tempTransfert AS T
                    USING (select 
                        case ISNULL(SUM([ProductItemWeight]) , 0)
                        when 0 then 0 
                        else SUM([ProductItemWeight]) 
                        end  
                        , ID 
                        from [ExplosiveTracking].[Production].[TransfertHistory]
                        where stuff(convert(varchar(20),TransfertDateTime,120),17,6,'') < stuff(convert(varchar(20),'2017-02-28 15:38:00',120),17,6,'')
                        Group by ID
                        ) as S ([ProductItemWeight],ID)

                    ON (T.ID = S.ID)
                    WHEN MATCHED  
                        THEN DELETE;


BUT when I added in the complete query as below , I have a SYNTAX error near MERGE reported :

            DECLARE @m_StoreTotalStock AS DECIMAL(18,3)
        DECLARE @mt_API AS TABLE
        (
            ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),   ASDATE DATETIME,ATDATE DATETIME, 
            ActionPlanItemID INT,   ActionPlanID INT, 
            ProductItemID INT,      ProductItemCode VARCHAR(50),
            QRCode VARCHAR(50),     Name VARCHAR(50), 
            StoreTotalStock decimal(18,3), ItemWeight decimal(18,3),
            Unit VARCHAR(50),       ItemQuantity INT, 
            ItemUnitWeight DECIMAL(18,4), ProductQuantity INT, 
            Emp1 VARCHAR(50),       Emp2 VARCHAR(50), 
            Emp3 VARCHAR(50),       Emp4 VARCHAR(50), 
            Sector VARCHAR(50),     ItemStatus TINYINT,ActionOver INt
        )

        DECLARE @mt_RemainingStockProduct AS TABLE
        (
            StoreID  INT,InventoryDate DATETIME,ProductID INT, TotalRemainingAtStore DECIMAL(18,2)
        )

            CREATE TABLE #tempTransfert 
    (
     [ID] uniqueidentifier,
     [ProductId] int,
     [SourceId] int,
     TransferDate DateTime,
     TotalMovedProduct DECIMAL(16,4)
     )

     Insert into #tempTransfert
        select
            [ID],[ProductId], [SourceId], stuff(convert(varchar(20),TransfertDateTime,120),17,6,'') as TransferDate, SUM([ProductItemWeight]) as TotalMovedProduct
        from [ExplosiveTracking].[Production].[TransfertHistory]
        group by [ProductId],ID, [SourceId], stuff(convert(varchar(20),TransfertDateTime,120),17,6,'')


        select * from #tempTransfert

        /** Get Remaining StockBy Product **/
        INSERT INTO @mt_RemainingStockProduct
        (
            StoreID, InventoryDate, ProductID,TotalRemainingAtStore
        )
        --SELECT InventoryDate, SUM(TotalRemainingAtStore) AS TotalRemainingAtStore FROM 
        --(
            SELECT StoreID, InventoryDate, ProductID, SUM(Remaining) OVER (PARTITION BY StoreID ) AS TotalRemainingAtStore FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    P.StoreID, P.InventoryDate, P.ProductID, 
                    --SUM(PIT.Quantity * P.ItemUnitWeight)-SUM(PIT.UsedQuantity * P.ItemUnitWeight) AS Remaining
                  SUM(PIT.Quantity * P.ItemUnitWeight) AS Remaining
                FROM Sales.Store AS S
                    INNER JOIN Production.ProductItem AS PIT 
                    INNER JOIN Production.Product AS P ON PIT.ProductID = P.ProductID 
                    INNER JOIN Production.UnitMeasure AS UM ON P.WeightUnitMeasureID = UM.UnitMeasureID ON 
                        S.BusinessEntityID = P.StoreID
                    INNER JOIN Production.Location AS LOC ON S.BusinessEntityID = LOC.StoreID AND 
                        P.LocationID = LOC.LocationID AND P.LocationID = LOC.LocationID

                WHERE   (P.IsDeleted = 0) AND (PIT.IsDeleted = 0) AND P.StoreID = 4
                GROUP BY P.StoreID,P.InventoryDate, P.ProductID, UM.UnitMeasureCode, S.Name, LOC.MaxQuantity
            ) AS RST1
        --) AS RST2
        --GROUP BY RST2.InventoryDate 

        /** Endof Get Remaining StockBy Product **/

        -- Get Store total product items weight
        SELECT @m_StoreTotalStock = SUM(PIW.TotalWeight) 
        FROM dbo.v_ProductItemWeight AS PIW
        WHERE StoreID = 4

        INSERT INTO @mt_API
        SELECT [dbo].fn_AddTimeZoneOffset(APHIST.ActionDate,'CET') AS ASDATE
            , [dbo].fn_AddTimeZoneOffset(APHIST.ReturnDate,'CET') AS ATDATE
            ,API_HIST.[ActionPlanItemID]
            ,API_HIST.[ActionPlanID]
            ,PIT.[ProductItemID]
            ,PIT.ProductItemCode
            ,PIT.QRCode
            ,PIT.Name
            ,ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 mRSP.TotalRemainingAtStore FROM @mt_RemainingStockProduct AS mRSP 
                WHERE mRSP.InventoryDate <= APHIST.ReturnDate
                ORDER BY mRSP.InventoryDate DESC), 0) AS StoreTotalStock
            ,P.[Weight] AS ItemWeight
            ,M.UnitMeasureCode as Unit
            ,PIT.Quantity AS ItemQuantity
            ,P.ItemUnitWeight
            ,P.Quantity as ProductQuantity
            ,E1.FullName AS Emp1
            ,E2.FullName AS Emp2
            ,E3.FullName AS Emp3
            ,E4.FullName AS Emp4
            ,SECT.Name AS Sector
            ,CASE WHEN n=0 then 0 else [ItemStatus] end as [ItemStatus]
            ,APHIST.IsActionOver as ActionOver
        FROM 
            [Sales].[ActionPlanItem_History] AS API_HIST
        INNER JOIN 
            [Sales].[ActionPlan_History] AS APHIST On APHIST.ActionPlanID =  API_HIST.ActionPlanID
        INNER JOIN
            [Production].[ProductItem] AS PIT ON API_HIST.ProductItemID =PIT.ProductItemID
        INNER JOIN
            Production.Product as P ON PIT.ProductID = P.ProductID AND PIT.ProductID = P.ProductID AND 
                PIT.ProductID = P.ProductID
        INNER JOIN
            Production.UnitMeasure as M ON M.UnitMeasureID = P.WeightUnitMeasureID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            Sales.Employee AS E1 ON APHIST.EmployeeID1 = E1.EmployeeID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            Sales.Employee AS E2 ON APHIST.EmployeeID2 = E2.EmployeeID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            Sales.Employee AS E3 ON APHIST.EmployeeID3 = E3.EmployeeID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            Sales.Employee AS E4 ON APHIST.EmployeeID4 = E4.EmployeeID 
        INNER JOIN
            Sales.Sector AS SECT ON APHIST.SectorID = SECT.SectorID
        INNER JOIN
            Production.ProductSubcategory as PS on P.ProductSubcategoryID=PS.ProductSubcategoryID
        INNER JOIN 
            Production.ProductCategory as PC on PS.ProductCategoryID= PC.ProductCategoryID

        CROSS APPLY (Values(0),(1)) d(n)
        WHERE  P.StoreID=4
        --WHERE PC.ProductCategoryID=@RootCategory AND P.StoreID=@StoreID

        --ORDER BY ProductItemCode, ATDATE 
        ORDER BY ASDATE , ProductItemCode

        SELECT 
             API1.ASDATE AS StartDate
            ,API1.ATDATE AS ReturnDate
            ,API1.ActionPlanItemID
            ,API1.ActionPlanID
            ,API1.ProductItemID
            ,API1.ProductItemCode
            ,API1.QRCode
            ,API1.Name
            ,API1.StoreTotalStock
            ,API1.ItemWeight
            ,API1.ItemQuantity
            ,API1.ItemUnitWeight
            ,API1.Unit
            ,API1.ProductQuantity
            ,API1.Emp1
            ,API1.Emp2
            ,API1.Emp3
            ,API1.Emp4
            ,API1.Sector
            ,API1.ItemStatus
            ,API1.ActionOver
            ,(API1.StoreTotalStock +
                (SELECT SUM(
                    CASE API2.ItemStatus 
                        WHEN 0 THEN -1
                        WHEN 1 THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 
                    END * API2.ItemUnitWeight) 
                FROM @mt_API AS API2
                    WHERE API2.ID <= API1.ID
                ) 

                    -

                    --select 
                    --  case ISNULL(SUM([ProductItemWeight]), 0)
                    --      when 0 then 0
                    --      else SUM([ProductItemWeight])
                    --  end  
                    --from [ExplosiveTracking].[Production].[TransfertHistory]
                    --where stuff(convert(varchar(20),TransfertDateTime,120),17,6,'') < stuff(convert(varchar(20),API1.ASDATE,120),17,6,'')
                (   
                    **MERGE #tempTransfert AS T
                        USING (select 
                            case ISNULL(SUM([ProductItemWeight]) , 0)
                            when 0 then 0 
                            else SUM([ProductItemWeight]) 
                            end  
                            , ID 
                            from [ExplosiveTracking].[Production].[TransfertHistory]
                            where stuff(convert(varchar(20),TransfertDateTime,120),17,6,'') < stuff(convert(varchar(20),API1.ASDATE,120),17,6,'')
                            Group by ID
                            ) as S ([ProductItemWeight],ID)

                        ON (T.ID = S.ID)
                        WHEN MATCHED  
                            THEN DELETE;
                )**
            ) AS ItemWeightBal

        FROM @mt_API  AS API1 
    END
```

The MERGE part is suppose to first return the SUM of ItemWeight within a DateTime range, then when those records has been read, I need to delete them from #tempTransfert table otherwise, on the next loop it will read all records again

Any idea what syntax error can it be ?

Thanks for your help on this
Regards

Comment: No, you cannot execute a delete inside a select query. You should describe better what you're trying to accomplish here. Can't you just run your delete after the insert?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*. It computes a scalar value. It doesn't let you stop in the middle of a `SELECT` statement and run arbitrary other statements.

Comment: I cannot run the delete after the INSERT, because the field API1.ASDATE is then not accessible.

I will update my post with something new

Comment: I agree that using a DELETE in a CASE sounds impossible.  When tackling this sort of issue I would use a OUTPUT ... INTO clause to get API1.ASDATE and other values needed from the INSERT into a table variable. Then use the table variable for the DELETE later on.   See Microsoft doco on OUTPUT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql